# How to understand the proof about Theorem 277 in "Inequalities by G. H. Hardy, J. E. Littlewood, G. Pólya"?

Tags: inequality

*picture1*:[image]
[image]

---

*picture2*:
[image]

term (8.3.5) is term (8.3.6). Now, i can not understand the red highlight line:why we choose the minimum $x_{i_{0}}y_{j_0}$, and how to show that $P_{i_0+j_0}$ is  unique and others $x_i=0,y_j=0$ for $i\neq i_0, j\neq j_0$?